# Group By MariaDB very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, mariadb

I'm using MariDB 10.1.18 under Linux.

I have a simple table (t) with the following structure:

```
| id | a | b |  c |
------------------- 
|  1 | 3 | 7 | 10 |
|  2 | 4 | 6 | 9  |
|  3 | 2 | 7 | 11 |
|  4 | 3 | 5 | 10 |
|  5 | 4 | 8 | 12 |
|  6 | 2 | 9 | 6  |


id is primary key
a - has BTREE index
b - has HASH index
c - has HASH index
```

I assume the Primary key gets indexed automatically.
My query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM t GROUP BY a
```

For performance purposes the ENGINE USED is `MEMORY`.

On 5 million rows, the above query takes **1 second** to complete and utilizes the thread of one CPU to 100%. There are about 150 unique values for column a right now.

I assumed that this could be solved if I used loose index search. Unfortunately this does not seem to work in MariaDB as it is never used. loosescan is set to on.

I have tried

```
SELECT MAX(a) FROM t GROUP BY a
```

Which takes 1.1 seconds on my database.

Question is, how can I make this select blazing fast? Like 0.05 seconds.

Thank you!

Comment: Pls post the results of the explain

Comment: One caveat: there is only so much you can achieve with standard development techniques. You may have to ask a DBA to configure your MySQL instance for higher performance.

Comment: The purpose is to filter out certain rows and then return the row with the highest c grouped by a. Ex: Select * FROM t WHERE b IN (5,6,7) AND a IN (2,3) GROUP BY a  SORT BY c DESC . However this will not give the proper results so a join is necessary. But I won't get into that.

Comment: It is not valid to select all columns, but `GROUP BY` only one.  Rethink that query.

Comment: @Shadow - CPU speeds have not changed much since the turn of the century; scanning 5M rows in RAM will take time.  0.05s is impossible without rewriting the query to avoid touching all 5M.

Comment: @Rick James - it is valid in MariaDB and mysql, but indeed it's not a valid SQL syntax. But this is exactly what I want to achieve, select one id for each column a where c is the highest. It does looks like it is almost impossible to have a quick query, but we are still investigating.

Comment: @SilviuT - [_Groupwise Max_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) has the most efficient "groupwise max" code I know of.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of work and testing this is the fastest solution so far:

1. Use Memory Engine - it's at least 10 times faster than InnoDB stored on RAMDISK
2. Make separate queries for every "a" column element instead of using Group BY and combine the results in PHP
   Ex. SELECT id FROM t WHERE b IN (3,4,5) AND c IN (6,7,8) AND a=1;
3. Set composite Index for each column like this INDEX ON (a,b) , INDEX ON (a,c) to give the planner enough flexibility for any type of query. INDEXES have to be BTREE.

A very complex query on a 5 mil row table now takes about 0.35 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really want. Both of your queries do not make much sense as they are.

```
SELECT MAX(a) FROM t GROUP BY a
```

can be rewritten to

```
SELECT a FROM t GROUP BY a
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM t
```

and it takes "zero" time.

Your first query will return the first row per group. Assuming you have no full-table-index - it will be the first row ordered by id. So its equivalent to "Find the oldest record per group", and can be rewritten to

```
select t.*
from (
    select min(id) as id
    from t
    group by a
) m
join t using(id)
```

And is also executed in "no time".

But queries like

```
select count(id) as id
from t
group by a
```

will be slow. Same with `SUM()` and `AVG()` because the engin needs to read every row. While `MIN()` and `MAX()` need to read only one row per group.

I have testet similar queries on an InnoDB table with 3.7 M rows and 30 groups.

Comment: Actually SELECT DISTINCT a FROM t takes aprox 0.7 seconds for 5 mil rows.

Comment: SELECT a FROM t GROUP BY a - takes also aprox 0.7 seconds .

Comment: I've testet my queries on a 3.7M-rows InnoDB-table (mysql 5.6.21) with 30 groups. After converting a copy to MyISAM, some queries became very slow. So try InnoDB!

Comment: Don't use `MEMORY` for speed; stick with InnoDB.

Comment: I have tried on disk InnoDB and it is significanly slower than MEMORY, almost 10 times lower. However, I have created a RAM disk and write the database in the RAM disk using the InnoDB engine. This way it is possible to still have speed while using InnoDB. It also seems that loose index scan only works with InnoDB and not Memory.